# AWS Lambda test run failure

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently learning AWS Lambda, and I'm trying to deploy a Lambda function whose inputs would be stored in a DynamoDB table(if that makes sense?), we were already given a source code to use and a separate code to test it.

I've checked both codes, refactored them, and started testing but somehow my results still return "failed" results. My code source is this:

```
const randomBytes = require('crypto').randomBytes;

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const fleet = [
{
    Name: 'Bucephalus',
    Color: 'Golden',
    Gender: 'Male',
},
{
    Name: 'Shadowfax',
    Color: 'White',
    Gender: 'Male',
},
{
    Name: 'Rocinante',
    Color: 'Yellow',
    Gender: 'Female',
},
  ];

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
if (!event.requestContext.authorizer) {
  errorResponse('Authorization not configured', context.awsRequestId, callback);
  return;
 }

const rideId = toUrlString(randomBytes(16));
console.log('Received event (', rideId, '): ', event);

// Because we're using a Cognito User Pools authorizer, all of the claims
// included in the authentication token are provided in the request context.
// This includes the username as well as other attributes.
const username = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims['cognito:username'];

// The body field of the event in a proxy integration is a raw string.
// In order to extract meaningful values, we need to first parse this string
// into an object. A more robust implementation might inspect the Content-Type
// header first and use a different parsing strategy based on that value.
const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

const pickupLocation = requestBody.PickupLocation;

const unicorn = findUnicorn(pickupLocation);

recordRide(rideId, username, unicorn).then(() => {
    // You can use the callback function to provide a return value from your Node.js
    // Lambda functions. The first parameter is used for failed invocations. The
    // second parameter specifies the result data of the invocation.

    // Because this Lambda function is called by an API Gateway proxy integration
    // the result object must use the following structure.
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 201,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            RideId: rideId,
            Unicorn: unicorn,
            UnicornName: unicorn.Name,
            Eta: '30 seconds',
            Rider: username,
        }),
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);

    // If there is an error during processing, catch it and return
    // from the Lambda function successfully. Specify a 500 HTTP status
    // code and provide an error message in the body. This will provide a
    // more meaningful error response to the end client.
    errorResponse(err.message, context.awsRequestId, callback);
});
};

function findUnicorn(pickupLocation) {
console.log('Finding unicorn for ', pickupLocation.Latitude, ', ', pickupLocation.Longitude);
return fleet[Math.floor(Math.random() * fleet.length)];
 }

function recordRide(rideId, username, unicorn) {
return ddb.put({
    TableName: 'AWSIES-jeremie.agravante',
    Item: {
        RideId: rideId,
        User: username,
        Unicorn: unicorn,
        UnicornName: unicorn.Name,
        RequestTime: new Date().toISOString(),
    },
}).promise();
}

 function toUrlString(buffer) {
return buffer.toString('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=/g, '');
}

function errorResponse(errorMessage, awsRequestId, callback) {
 callback(null, {
statusCode: 500,
  body: JSON.stringify({
  Error: errorMessage,
  Reference: awsRequestId,
}),
headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
}
});
}
```

And the test code is this:

```
 {
 "path": "/ride",
 "httpMethod ": "POST",
 "headers": {
 "Accept": "*/*",
 "Authorization": "eyJraWQiOiJLTzRVMWZs",
 "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF 8"
 },
 "queryStringParameters ":"null",
 "pathParameters ":"null",
 "requestContext ": {
 "authorizer": {
 "claims": {
   "cognito:username ": "the_username"
  }
  }
  },
  "body": "{\"PickupLocation \": 
    {\"Latitude\":47.6174755835663,\"Longitude\":-122.28837066650185}}"
  }
```

The error that it throws me is this:

```
Test Event Name:testRequestEvent

Response
{
 "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
"trace": [
"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
"    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
"    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
"    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
"    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)",
"    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)",
"    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)",
"    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)",
"    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)",
"    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
]
}

 Function Logs
 START RequestId: 2f5c85af-632f-4fa2-8a32-46547e84fe64 Version: $LATEST
 2021-11-18T01:39:55.279Z   undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception   
 {"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of 
 input","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input","    at 
 _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load 
 (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> 
 (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)","    at Module.load 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)","    at Function.Module._load 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
 (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
  2021-11-18T01:39:56.826Z  undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception   
  {"errorType":"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input","stack":["Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
   END RequestId: 2f5c85af-632f-4fa2-8a32-46547e84fe64
 REPORT RequestId: 2f5c85af-632f-4fa2-8a32-46547e84fe64 Duration: 1714.81 ms    Billed 
 Duration: 1715 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 12 MB  
 Unknown application error occurred
 Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError

 Request ID
  2f5c85af-632f-4fa2-8a32-46547e84fe64
```

I'm sorry if this is really long, but I could really use a hand in this one. I keep looking for syntax errors even found some bugs that my instructors have purposely snuck in to test us, but I guess my beginner skills are not enough at the moment. Thanks to anyone who could help.

Comment: I'd recommend deploying a much simpler Lambda function to start with, for example the first example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html). Learn how to package, deploy, and test that first. Then add your require statements and test that. Then introduce the remaining code and test that.

Comment: Okay. That seems like a good idea, I will surely do.